# Is the installation for pip off PyPa safe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Is the download of the binary from PyPA safe, I was able to download it and install it via my terminal on Mac OS yet the sight of downloading the binary from >> https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py makes me paranoid, it didn't help that the paragraph uses the word "paranoid". Is the download from this bootstrap page safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe. Look at they repositories on github: https://github.com/pypa

PyPa is the Python Packaging Authority is the group behind pip.